# TypeError: must be string or buffer, not instance

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am using django-jsignature in my django project. After making the post request, the form returns "type 'instance'". I'm trying to save this as an image, but I get the above error.

Even better would be to save the form data as a vector image as suggested in the docs.

My function:

```
def signature(request):
    form = SignatureForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        signature = form.cleaned_data.get('signature')
        if signature:
            # as an image
            signature_picture = draw_signature(signature)
            signature_file_path = draw_signature(signature, as_file=True)
            with open(signature_file_path), 'wb') as f:
                f.write(signature_picture)
```

(signature_file_path == '/tmp/tmpB71Wft.PNG')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the docs are a bit unclear, but you should be using either `draw_signature(data, as_file=False)` (default) OR `draw_signature(data, as_file=True)`, no need for both.

Passing a `True` value to `as_file` makes the package [dump the image content to a file](https://github.com/fle/django-jsignature/blob/master/jsignature/utils.py#L46), while `False` makes it return the [PIL.Image](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html) instance.

The raw data is still available in your `signature` variable (as JSON string or list, so you could also use that vector directly.

Answer (score 0):

Can draw_signature() take one or two arguments?  Your code has it taking one argument in one location, and a two arguments in a second location.